# ReactiveX Java process finishing early?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, reactivex

```
public class ReactiveExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, NumberFormatException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        Observable.range(1, 5).subscribe(
                System.out::println,
                error -> System.out.println("error"),
                () -> System.out.println("completed")
        );

    }

}
```

The result that is printed out is `rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable@2fad386b`

After the observable is printed I get:

`Process finished with exit code 0`.

I just started out with ReactiveX and have been following a few tutorials. My assumption was that the code above will continuously stream data as such:

`1-2-3-4-5-1-2-3-4-5...` and continue to print the value. Why does my program stop immediately? Does it just end after the first 5 digits have been observed? How can I change this to continuously stream values and print them as those values are looped through? Also, how do I actually print the values instead of the observable object reference?

Comment: Because range completes when it reaches the end of the range

Answer (score 1):

`range: Returns an Observable that emits a sequence of Integers within a specified range.`

So your assumption is wrong. `range` does not repeat anything. For that you need to use `repeat`

```
Observable.range(1, 5).repeat().subscribe(
  System.out::println,
  error -> System.out.println("error"),
  () -> System.out.println("completed")
);
```